# What are "enterprise-level capabilities" for application servers?

Tags: enterprise, application-server

I've been reading about application servers, and the term "enterprise-level capabilities" show up very often. It sounds like a vague term that we, developers, use a lot (just like "cloud").

What does it mean when the server has "enterprise-level capabilities"?
What can the server do to support [enterprise-level applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161991/what-makes-an-application-an-enterprise-or-enterprise-level-application)?
What should I expect from these types of application servers?

Any list of things that can be considered would be great, because I have no idea what makes up "enterprise-level capabilities".

It would be great if there are definitions depending on different perspectives (e.g. from developers, architecture, and business point of view).

Comment: As you said, it's vague. Too many diverse definitions. Buzzword.

Comment: @Mehrdad: But it should indicate something or many things. I just want to know what it is even indicating, because I have no idea what this comes with. It's more of an "empty" word to me right now.

Answer (score 1):

"Expensive."

Answer (score 1):

It's a vague (and thus largely meaningless) term.

It could mean that the solution scales, but you have scaling up and scaling out, and the preference for each could depend on the enterprise.

It could mean that it has high-availability features (again, different enterprises would have different preferences for failover modes).

If could mean that that it can handle a large amount of data (for instance Quicken would not be considered Enterprise if you expected it to handle the accounts of 10m customers).  However, an enterprise system which handles a state-wide bank is a lot different than one that can handle an international bank.

In all cases it means the pricing is always "call for quote" and you'll be paying a lot of money.  (But "a lot of money' varies by enterprise)

Comment: so 10m customer base is not big enough to be considered as "enterprise-level"?

Comment: My point was that Quicken can handle some enterprises up to a certain size.  However, I would not attempt to use it to manage the accounts of 10m customers of my business.  Part of the problem is that even two enterprises of the same number of employees or revenue or whatever metric can be vastly different.